# How to create a 2D mesh along a specified path?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, mesh

I am trying to create a mesh along specific lines connecting specific points. Here I used `Subdivide` to create `n` steps along the path that connects points `p1` and `p2` such that the size of the step is the same along each path. I would like to specify the size of the step instead of the number of steps in `Subdivide` like in the case with `Range`, is that possible? I need to do that to avoid problems in my code: first, the last point from each path is repeated which can be avoided using `DeleteDuplicates` in the final list, second, the size of the step is not exactly the same but become almost the same when the number of steps is very large. So, specifying the size of the step can solve both problems.

```
getPath[n_, p1_, p2_, normpthLngth_] := 
  Subdivide[p1, p2, (n IntegerPart[Norm[p1 - p2]])/
   IntegerPart[normpthLngth] ];
pontspath = {{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {0, 0}};
PathFnl = 
  Flatten[Table[
    getPath[10, pontspath[[i]], pontspath[[i + 1]], 
     Norm[pontspath[[1]] - pontspath[[2]]]], {i, 1, 
     Length[pontspath] - 1}], 1];
ListPlot[PathFnl]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `Range` instead? i.e `Range[min, max, step]`

Comment: @flinty it is not working when min={x0,y0} and max={x1,y1} but it is magically working with Subdivide

Comment: hmm, what exactly do you mean by specifying the "size of the step" two-dimensionally? like the norm of the vector pointing in the direction of the second point?

Comment: does `nDRange[p1_, p2_, stepsize_] := Transpose@Range[p1, p2, stepsize Normalize[p2 - p1]]` work for you?

Comment: to see what this produces, evaluate it and then try `Manipulate[ListPlot[{nDRange[{3, 4}, {6, 9}, step], {{3, 4}, {6, 9}}}], {step, 0.1, 2}]`

Comment: @thorimur, but it will not work if the path along the y-axis, e.g  p1={0,0} and p2={0,10}. It would be nice if the path in the fig. can be produced with your approach

Comment: ah, good point! here's the old-fashioned way, then: `nDRange[p1_, p2_, stepsize_] := 
 Table[p1 + x*Normalize[p2 - p1], {x, 0, Norm[p2 - p1], stepsize}]`. lmk if it's what you want—note that you could exclude the first point by using `stepsize` instead of `0` in the table iteration spec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DiscretizeRegion` of a `Line` and `MaxCellMeasure` to specify the (maximum)  length of line segments:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {0, 0}};
mesh = DiscretizeRegion[Line[points], MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> .5}]
newcoords = MeshCoordinates[mesh]
```

[image]

For the `ListLinePlot` you may need to sort the points as they come out of `MeshCoordinates` in a weird order sometimes:

```
ListLinePlot[newcoords[[Last@FindShortestTour@newcoords]], 
 Mesh -> All, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: that is cool., thanks a lot. just one more thing, is it possible to arrange the mesh points along the paths   connecting the points such that we get a clean `ListLinePlot[newcoords]`

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility might be:

```
ListLinePlot[
    {{0,0},{0,10},{10,10},{0,0}},
    MeshFunctions->{"ArcLength"},
    Mesh->23
]
```

[image]

The problem is that the mesh will typically not contain the original points.

Comment: that is nice but how can we get the list of points as  list=`{xi,yi}`?